# Why MTP mounted files belong to root?

Tags: permissions, filesystem, android, root, mtp

Xubuntu Saucy and an Android device running Kitkat. I connect it to my computer and it is mounted as MTP but the files on it belong to root so I can't modify them. Why is this and how can I change it?

Comment: Please update to a still supported release and confirm that the issue still persists. Please [edit] your question accordingly and state which exact device you are using and if you are using anything else than nautilus/mtp-gvfs backend to connect the device.